# XMLHttpRequest get request response is empty, even with callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, get

I'm attempting to get a response from a Node application I created using the XMLHttpRequest object in JavaScript. The code I am using to do such is below:

```
var get = function()
{       
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest({mozSystem: true});
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.status === 200) {
        console.log(http.responseText);
      }
    }
    http.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:3000", true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    http.send();    
}
```

And the Node application is:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => 
{
    let body = [];
    req.on('data', (chunk) =>
    {  
        body.push(chunk);
    }).on('end', () => 
    {
        body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
        if(req.method === "GET")
        {
            console.log("GET"); 
        }
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.end("Hello World");
  })
});
```

However, nothing is being printed. I opened the developer tools in Chrome and Mozilla and can see that the status is 200, and the response is listed under the response for the Ajax call - it says clearly "Hello World".

I'm doing this all locally, as a Node demo for school. I have the application able to handle post requests perfectly fine - but getting the response from the GET request does not seem to work. I'm open to any and all advice!

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: if `http://127.0.0.1:3000` is a different server to that which served the page itself, then you better enable **CORS** in whatever is running on port 3000

Comment: or perhaps `http.status === 200` before `http.readyState === 4` ... use `onload` instead of old school `onreadystatechange` - because when readyState === 2, headers are received, including presumably the response status ... but the body of the response is yet to come - there's about a bazillion examples of using `onreadystatechange` - I'm surprised you got it so wrong - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange

Comment: @JaromandaX, enabling CORS worked - I did not realize it would be so simple. Additionally, I did try onload, as well as a variety of implementations using onreadystatechange - all of which did not work. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question, I was not aware that not having CORs enabled would cause such behavior - the browser would show that the request was going through, the response could be seen in developer tools, but could not be printed to console. Thank you to Jaromanda for helping me come to realize this.